# SLLN for iid $X_n$

Tags: law-of-large-numbers

For i.i.d $X_n$'s with $E[(X_1)_-]<+\infty$ and $E[(X_1)_+]=+\infty$, I want to prove that $$\frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i=1}^nX_i\xrightarrow{\text{a.e}} +\infty$$ as $n\xrightarrow{}+\infty$.

I know that I have to use the Strong Law of Large numbers but I am confused on how to implement it. I think I have to find out that the mean of $\Sigma X_i$ is infinity.

I also found in my notes that $n^{-1}S_n\xrightarrow{\text{a.e}}\mu$ as $n\xrightarrow{}\infty$ whenever $E[X_1]<\infty$ and $S_n=\Sigma_{i=1}^nX_i$.

I would appreciate any answers to this.

Comment: What is $(X_1)_-$ supposed to mean?

Comment: $E[X_1]=\mu$ @MishaLavrov

Comment: That's not my question. What is the meaning of the notation $(X_1)_-$ and $(X_1)_+$?

Comment: It is the negative and positive part of $X$. @MishaLavrov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_i^M(\omega) = \min\{X_i(\omega), M\}$, and $S_n^M=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^M$. Then almost surely:
$$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{S_n}n\ge\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac1nS_n^M = E(X_1^M)$$
By monotone convergence, $E(X_{1,+}^M)\rightarrow\infty$ as $M\rightarrow\infty$, and since $E(X_{1,-}^M)=E(X_{1,-})<\infty$, the claim follows.